# Ignore Content-Length of an http response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, http-headers

I need to make an http request to an external service which indicates that it has a mismatch on the Content-Length of its response. I can't find information about how to ignore that Content-Length or if it affects to the length of the response body.

This is the code that I have been using to make the request:

```
req = Net::HTTP::POST.new(url, headers)
req.body = body
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
response = http.request(req)
body = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Does the code you prove work?

Comment: The above code works fine but when I make the JSON.parse, it fails sometimes. When it fails and I read the response body, I can see that the last character doesn't appear. The external service has a mismatch on the Content-Length header of the response and I don't know if it is causing the problem or it doesn't affect.

Comment: ah, ok. First, it's very unlikely that the Content-Length is not set correctly, because it's virtually never set manually, as it belongs to the HTTP layer itself, and is set with corresponding libraries which are thoroughly tested. And even if it's not, I don't think it's a good idea to "ignore" it, better contact the service provider and point them to the error.

Comment: Thanks for all. I will do it.

Comment: cool! I'll post it as an answer then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it's very unlikely that the Content-Length is not set correctly by any service, as it's virtually never set manually, it belongs to the underlying HTTP layer itself, and is set with corresponding libraries which are thoroughly tested.

And even if it's not, I don't think it's a good idea to "ignore" it, better contact the service provider and point them to the error.